# Passing children when calling stateless functional component

Tags: reactjs

So I am trying to optimise my app by converting various components to stateless functional ones and I have come across the conundrum of what to do when `props.children` needs to be rendered. My understanding is that you need to use a function call instead of the element syntax in order to see any performance gains. I was just wondering if method 2 below is the proper way of doing this, or it could have any unexpected side effects. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
const APP = (props) => {
    return <b>{props.children}</b>
};

const child1 = <p>Hello</p>;
const child2 = <p>world</p>;


// method 1 (usual jsx element syntax)
ReactDOM.render(
   <APP>{child1}{child2}</APP>,
   document.getElementById('container')
);

// method 2
ReactDOM.render(
   APP({children: [child1, child2]}),
   document.getElementById('container')
);
```

Comment: I would just use method 1. JSX in the end is just syntactic sugar for `React.createElement()`. You could write your apps using that actual method, but it would look very hideous and hard to maintain. Just use JSX and be happy.

Comment: My understanding is that the second method above is more efficient because `React.createElement` doesn't need to be  called - hence my desire to use it. I was just wondering if this was the best way to go about not using the jsx syntax here.

Comment: @AndrewWinterbotham Yes you are correct! [Calling stateless components as functions do offer a significant performance gain over using `React.createElement`.](https://medium.com/missive-app/45-faster-react-functional-components-now-3509a668e69f) I would go with your second option if performance is a real issue. But, the first option is more readable and understandable by other React devs.

Comment: @ChaseDeAnda thanks for the conformation! I have yet to decide whether I will go for performance or readability :)